# How to save nas's all files path info into one file? Only 10M RAM Free

Tags: python

How to save nas's all files path info into one file? 
The problem is the nas only have 10MB RAM Free.

Using python on nas linux.

Comment: do you mean something like "find  / -type f >> pathes" but on python?

Comment: Yes,include file size/date, I want to use this to Sort out hundreds of thousands of files classified

Comment: I use this
find -type f | xargs ls -lrt -d -1 $PWD/* | awk '{print $5,$6,$7,$8,$9 > "filetree"}'

Then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
find -type f | xargs ls -lrt -d -1 $PWD/* | awk '{print $5,$6,$7,$8,$9}' | your_python_program.py
```

your python_program.py:

```
...
for line in sys.stdin:
   #process input
```

Or `os.walk` within function-generator like this:

```
def f():
    w = os.walk('/')
    for path in w:
        if os.path.isfile(path[0]) yield path[0]
```

second one may not work if there are A LOT of files within one dir

Comment: I use this

    find -type f | xargs ls -lrt -d -1 $PWD/* | awk '{print $5,$6,$7,$8,$9 > "filetree"}'

Then get filetree Size is 5MB , I found filetree not include all files path.
I think the nas has only 10MB Free memory so i can not write file large than 5MB. Other way?

Comment: You do not need to save path into file, just pipe stdout to your program to perform other actions. $man find to choose needed options